# Converting hourly data in to minute python

Tags: python, time-series, data-science

I have a dataset that contains hourly data where data is coming from a sensor-

```
    date                 Fea-1     Fea-2
0   01-01-1990 00:00    0.0000     0.000
1   01-01-1990 01:00    0.0000     0.000
2   01-01-1990 02:00    0.0000     0.000
3   01-01-1990 03:00    0.0000     0.000
4   01-01-1990 04:00    0.0000     0.000
5   01-01-1990 05:00    0.0000     0.000
6   01-01-1990 06:00    0.4986     0.000
7   01-01-1990 07:00    69.3000    68.725
8   01-01-1990 08:00    171.6000   168.870
9   01-01-1990 09:00    368.3000   372.240
10  01-01-1990 10:00    358.1000   353.210
11  01-01-1990 11:00    393.3000   387.430
12  01-01-1990 12:00    385.9000   379.120
13  01-01-1990 13:00    312.6000   304.240
14  01-01-1990 14:00    199.3100   190.820
15  01-01-1990 15:00    58.9960    54.509
16  01-01-1990 16:00    21.8040    19.572
17  01-01-1990 17:00    7.1959     0.000
18  01-01-1990 18:00    0.0000     0.000
19  01-01-1990 19:00    0.0000     0.000
```

Now I want to convert the every hour data to minute data like-

```
01-01-1990 00:01
01-01-1990 00:02
01-01-1990 00:03
01-01-1990 00:04
upto ..
01-01-1990 00:60
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen to the `Fea-1` and `Fea-2` columns as a result of resampling the data?

Comment: it should also be as per minute wise

Comment: You can interpolate the other datasets, but be aware there will be interpolation error.

Comment: @Steve Can you please provide the code for interpolation? can I use this interpolation data for model training will it be reliable

Comment: The default interpolant will be linear interpolation. This has an advantage that your data will never go negative (which I expect it would for e.g. spline) but it won't look smooth. For model training, I don't know if it will add more information that you already have, because it will just be data inferred from what's there now.

Comment: Thanks, @steve for sharing the link. I have one more question, what are the different interpolation techniques we can use?

Comment: There's nearest, bfill and fill which will each be piecewise constant (flat and then jump). Spline will be smooth but might go negative where your data increases sharply. I've had good experience with pchip, which will be piecewise monotonic (only increasing or decreasing between hours). Not too familiar with others - try them and plot your datasets (especially just before the increase from 0).